# ¿Cuantos bytes soporta un String en android? No se muestra toda la información en LogCat

Tags: android-studio

Me encuentro en un problema en android studio, estoy usando `Socket` e `InputStream`, cada 2 segundos obtengo una cadena larga de caracteres para luego meterlo en un `Array` y recorrer con un `for`, mi problema es que la cadena de caracteres no llega completamente o mi variable String no logra tomar bien los caracteres.

Un ejemplo, por `InputStream` yo obtengo esta cadena caracteres:

```
1,23.23,4.34:2,21.23,5.34:1,23.34,4.34:1,43.23,4.34:2,21.23,5.34:1,23.34,4.34:1,12.12,4.34:2,21.23,5.34:1,23.34,4.34:
```

puede ser hasta mas larga y en android studio así es como lo recibo:

```
while (true) {
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.0.30");
                Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, 8080);

                // PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                // out.println("");
                InputStream stream = socket.getInputStream();
                byte[] lenBytes = new byte[1300];
                stream.read(lenBytes,0,1300);

                 received = new String(lenBytes, "UTF-8").trim();
                Log.d("received",received);
            }
```

en LogCat logro ver lo que obtengo y siempre me llegan datos cortos y algunos completos, después de eso la variable `received` la paso como un parámetro en un método donde comienzo a separar por comas y dos puntos.

Es algún problema del `byte[`]? necesito ayuda de cual es la manera para obtener esa gran cantidad de caracteres por `inputStream`.

Comment: En general los metodos que reciben paquetes, no reciben nunca toda la informacion de un tiro, si no que hay que seguir recibiendo datos hasta que no haya mas. No veo eso en tu codigo, y puede ser ese tu problema.

Comment: Como comenta gbianchi, regularmente la información que se recibe se almacena cada n bytes, en tu caso 1300 bytes, pero debes interar para obtener toda la información , agregué respuesta, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Hay 2 causas por las cuales tu información no se despliegue completamente en el LogCat:

Primeramente debes asegurar obtener la información, veo que tienes definido un buffer de 1300 bytes para almacenar la información, si tu información es mayor, esta será truncada, lo que debes realizar es iterar para obtener información recibida como `InputStream` y almacenarla cada 1300 bytes:

```
InputStream stream = socket.getInputStream();

ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

int nRead;
byte[] lenBytes = new byte[1300];

//itera para almacenar información en buffer.
while ((nRead = stream.read(lenBytes, 0, lenBytes.length)) != -1) {
  buffer.write(lenBytes, 0, nRead);
}

String received = Arrays.toString(buffer.toByteArray());

Log.d("received",received);
```

---

Otra causa por la cual podrías no visualizar toda la información es la capacidad del buffer configurada en el `LogCat`.

> En el `LogCat` logro ver lo que obtengo y siempre me llegan datos cortos y
>   algunos completos,

Aunque tengas los datos almacenados en una variable, **debes tomar en cuenta que `LogCat` tienen un tamaño de buffer definido  para almacenar datos. Si los datos a imprimir en el `LogCat` son mayores al tamaño de este buffer, la información no se mostrará completa.**

Regularmente para dispositivos la medida predeterminada son 256Kb de información que se muestra en el `LogCat`.

Si deseas ver la información sobre la medida de tu buffer usa el ADB, que se encuentra dentro de `androidSDK\platform-tools` y ejecuta el comando:

`adb logcat -g`

Aquí un ejemplo, una comparación entre un `LogCat` que imprime información muestra un determinado consumo y cuando se elimina la información , se libera el buffer, 0 bytes de consumo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Es algún problema del byte[]? necesito ayuda de cual es la manera para
>   obtener esa gran cantidad de caracteres por inputStream.

Te podría asegurar que no es un problema , simplemente no se puede imprimir toda la información en el `LogCat`.

```
        InputStream stream = socket.getInputStream();
        byte[] lenBytes = new byte[1300];
        stream.read(lenBytes,0,1300);
        received = new String(lenBytes, "UTF-8").trim();

        Log.d("received",received);
```

#### Cambiar medida de buffer usado por el LogCat.

Si deseas cambiar el tamaño del buffer puedes usar `adb logcat -G <size>` , ejemplos:

Cambia a 1 MegaByte:

```
adb logcat -G 1M
```

Cambia a 256 KiloBytes:

```
adb logcat -G 256K
```